# Linq query to return unique values inside a specific field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a basic classt(Entity Framework) named Post as is:

```
Public class Post
{
    Public int Id { get; set; }
    Public string Description { get; set; }
    Public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The `Tags` property contains a list of tags for the post (comma separated).

Is it possible to have a Linq which return all different tags present in the Post entity?

So for example if I have:

- 1: java, cobol, foxpro
- 2: sybase, foxpro
- 3: cobol, csharp

The result should be: java, cobol, foxpro, sybase, csharp

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot That wouldn't work because of the comma separator.

Comment: Well, can you figure out how to `Split` the individual tags out of one string? Can you figure out how to `Select` `Distinct` tags once they're separated?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `Split()` and `SelectMany()`.

```
posts.SelectMany(x => x.Tags.Split(',')).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going to be able to do this in one step, because the things you need to do to split and recombine the comma-separated string aren't exposed through LINQ to Entities. You'll need to pull back the data first, then process the tags.

```
var tags = db.Posts.Select(p => p.Tags)
             .Distinct() // let SQL save us a little work, if some posts have same sets of tags
             .ToList()   // this causes the query to execute
             .SelectMany(t => t.Split(',')) // this happens client-side
             .Distinct();
```

Comment: If i where you i would use AsEnumerable() instead of ToList() in this query. AsEnumerable say that after that all work is on client but not materialize query.